# Converting Bitmap to TIFF in Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imagemagick, jmagick

I am working on a project that has an external API that I need to submit an image through, and the requirement of that API is that the image be a TIFF with Group 4 Compression.  I have tried several different approaches to convert my Bitmap to a TIFF including using JAI imageio in Android, porting libtiff into NDK and using OpenCV.  JAI imageio is commonly recommend on here as a possible solution, but I found that even when I found a standalone version of JAI imageio that I still had an unmet dependency on javax.imageio and as a result could not build my app.  Porting libtiff should work, and I have a branch in my code where I have begun this process, but due to the time required to do this I would prefer an alternate solution.  OpenCV I also started to implement, but I decided the requirement to install a secondary OpenCV Manager APK in order to use it is not acceptable for my app, in addition to this being significant overkill for solving a simple problem.

Currently I have been working with the Android port of ImageMagick found here https://github.com/paulasiimwe/Android-ImageMagick and this appears to be a promising approach.  So far I have set it up in my app and am able to output the image to a file in order to verify the image.  I am able to use it to convert to a couple different image formats, but when I try to convert to a TIFF I receive a SIGSEGV and the app crashes.

The relevant code snippet is:

```
MagickImage image = MagickBitmap.fromBitmap(sizedImage);
image.setMagick("TIFF");
image.setImageFormat("TIFF");
image.setDepth(1);
image.setCompression(CompressionType.Group4Compression);

ImageInfo info = new ImageInfo();
info.setMagick("TIFF");
info.setCompression(CompressionType.Group4Compression);

image.writeImage(info);
```

I have tried various permutations of the different calls to setMagick and setCompression, all of which yield the same result.  If a call to setMagick("TIFF") is made, then when it reaches image.writeImage(info) the app will crash with the following output:

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 2283
```

Has anyone used ImageMagick in Android to convert to a TIFF, or does anyone know of a clean method of converting to a TIFF in Android that is verified to actually work.  I know that it must be possible because there are apps on the Play Store for converting image formats which include converting to TIFF, including one from Paul Asiimwe, who published this Android port.

EDIT #1:

By using the following code I am able to get an uncompressed TIFF that appears to be correct in all other regards, but it just will not compress it to Group 4 compression.

```
MagickImage image = MagickBitmap.fromBitmap(sizedImage);
image.setDepth(1);
image.setNumberColors(2);
ImageInfo info = new ImageInfo(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/output.tiff");
image.setCompression(CompressionType.Group4Compression);
image.writeImage(info);

info.setColorspace(ColorspaceType.GRAYColorspace);
info.setMonochrome(1);
info.setCompression(CompressionType.Group4Compression);
image.writeImage(info);

byte[] blob = image.imageToBlob(info);
```

Comment: Sorry, I've just seen this now. But you figured it out.
My android port of ImageMagick should be able to convert most images to TIFF. The Issue is the compression flags. 
As with other abilities and formats I've tried in this port, such as converting to a .pdf, they crash occasionally with a sigsegv 11.  
The issue seems to stem from the C/C++ end of the library not being optimized for use on Android Devices. So memory leaks Happen.

i've unfortunately been unable to completely optimize the port for android. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to have to implement your own manual tiff conversion in this case.

Comment: I ended up writing a library to convert bitmaps to tiffs with Group 4 compression.

Comment: Could you please share your library which is used to convert bitmap to tiff. I have a requirement that , i want to merge multiple tiff images into one single tiff image in android. Can you please help me in this.

Comment: The library is part of a commercial application that is not open source and so I can not share it.  However I can certainly help you work with tiffs.  First, when you say merge are you wanting to take multiple images and turn them into a single multi page tiff where each page is one of the images, or are you wanting to make a single page tiff that contains the images together on one page?  Either way, my library probably wouldn't help you anyways as it is restricted to single page monochrome tiffs with either no compression or Group 4 compression, and also only covers converting one way.

Comment: Also, if the images are already provided as a tiff it is a lot easier to leave them as tiffs and combine them if you are just wanting to make a multi page tiff.  Tiff structure consists of a file header section that designates the byte order used in the tiff, the fact that it is a tiff and the offset to the first Image File Directory. If you follow the offset to the IFD it will tell you the type of compression used for that image, as well as other things and the offset to the data for that image and then the offset to the next IFD.  Using this information you can get all of the blocks of data.

Comment: Using that information you can create a new tiff with a file header very similar to the other tiff file headers, but you will need to modify the offsets for the new file.  You will then need to add both IFDs to the new tiff and the two blocks of image data, modifying the offsets accordingly, but the key savings is you won't need to decode and recode the image data.
[Adobe specs, covers file structure](https://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf)
Hopefully, all images use the same byte order, otherwise it can be messy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my library. It can save bitmap as tiff image 
https://github.com/Beyka/Android-TiffBitmapFactory

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).